# How to find the largest concatenated number that can be constructed by concatenating all the elements of the given array without using strings?

Tags: java, backtracking

**Actually I am only adding the answer to this just to share the another approach, nothing other than that.**

Constraints:

1 <= N <= 1000

0 <= ar[i] <= 1000

The first line N denotes the number of elements in an array

and the second line consists of array elements

**Example:**

2

100, 9

output: 9100

**Example 2:**

3

12, 13, 8

Output: 81312

Comment: I'm not sure i understand the question. If you want this to be useful for future readers (and I suppose you do, or you wouldn't have self-answered) then I would expand on the problem more

Comment: Do you try to post a question and your own answer, in order to provide a solution for others with a similiar problem? In that case I suggest you read  about [Answering your own Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), add details to the problem description, and wait for others to provide an alternative solution before posting your own. If you want your solution to be improved, check https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: while asking a question, do try to show the level of effort put in finding the solutions and the exact place where you are stuck and need help. Just putting some DA/Algo problem doesn't qualify to be a stackoverflow question.

Answer (score -1):

**This code won't work for big numbers and it is not an efficient solution in terms of time complexity**

**Due to some misunderstanding my post was deleted please consider this it is my question and my solution only due to someone has suggested the edit the answer was added to the question as "My code so far:"**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;


public class Solution 

{

    static long ans=0;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int N,count=0;
        long n;


        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        N=scan.nextInt();

        long[] ar=new long[N];
        long[] vis=new long[N];
        for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
        {
            ar[i]=scan.nextLong();
            vis[i]=0;
            n=ar[i];
            while(n!=0)
           {
                n/=10;
                count++;//It counts the number of digits of all elements in the given array
           }

       }      

       int index=0;
       long val=0,a=0;
       int x=0;

       recur(ar,vis,index,N,count,val,a);
       System.out.println(ans);
    }

    static void recur(long ar[],long vis[],int index,int N,int count,long val,long a)
    {
        if(index==N)
        {
            ans=Math.max(ans,val);
            return;
        }
        for(int i=0,j=0;i<N;i++,j++)
        {
            if(vis[i]==0)
            {
                vis[i]=1;
                a=counter(ar[i]);//counter returns no. of digits in the current element
                count-=a;//this returned value is subtracted from the count(which is the number of digits of all elements in the array)

                val+=ar[i]*(Math.pow(10,count));// now the corresponding digit's place is multiplied with the element to make up the number

                recur(ar,vis,index+1,N,count,val,a);
                vis[i]=0;
                val-=ar[i]*(Math.pow(10,count));
                count+=a;
            }
        }
    }
    static long counter(long val)
    {
        int count=0;
        while(val!=0)
        {
            val/=10;
            count++;
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is you code so far, then don't post it as an answer - edit your original question. That is why your post was deleted before.